# Converting a data buffer (YUV) to QImage (RGBA)

Tags: c++, qt

I'm trying to convert an image buffer with YUV data to a QImage (RGBA8888 format).

Here is the conversion from the buffer to an IplImage :

```
void DeckLinkCaptureDelegate::convertFrameToOpenCV(void* frameBytes, IplImage * m_RGB){
    if(!m_RGB)  m_RGB = cvCreateImage(cvSize(width, height), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 3);


    unsigned char* pData = (unsigned char *) frameBytes;

    for(int i = 0, j=0; i < width * height * 3; i+=6, j+=4)
    {

        unsigned char u = pData[j];
        unsigned char y = pData[j+1];
        unsigned char v = pData[j+2];

        //fprintf(stderr, "%d\n", v);
        m_RGB->imageData[i+2] = 1.0*y + 8 + 1.402*(v-128);               // r
        m_RGB->imageData[i+1] = 1.0*y - 0.34413*(u-128) - 0.71414*(v-128);   // g
        m_RGB->imageData[i] = 1.0*y + 1.772*(u-128) + 0;                            // b

        y = pData[j+3];
        m_RGB->imageData[i+5] = 1.0*y + 8 + 1.402*(v-128);               // r
        m_RGB->imageData[i+4] = 1.0*y - 0.34413*(u-128) - 0.71414*(v-128);   // g
        m_RGB->imageData[i+3] = 1.0*y + 1.772*(u-128) + 0;
    }


}
```

The goal would be to replace IplImage * m_RGB to a QImage object. The format of the QImage can be change later with a Qt function to convert QImage format. I've managed to get a QImage from the IplImage but I'm trying to bypass this step to completely remove the IplImage step.

The problem is, I'm having a hard time understanding the code above so I don't know how I could do it for a QImage.

Could you help me do it or at least understand the code above ?

Thanks.

EDIT : Here is what I have for the moment but it's not working.

```
void DeckLinkCaptureDelegate::convertFrameToOpenCV(void* frameBytes, QImage m_RGB){
    //if(!m_RGB)  m_RGB = QImage(width, height, QImage::Format_RGB888);


    unsigned char* pData = (unsigned char *) frameBytes;


    for(int i = 0, j=0; i < width * height * 3; i+=6, j+=4)
    {

        unsigned char u = pData[j];
        unsigned char y = pData[j+1];
        unsigned char v = pData[j+2];

        //fprintf(stderr, "%d\n", v);


        m_RGB.bits()[i+2] = 1.0*y + 8 + 1.402*(v-128);               // r
        m_RGB.bits()[i+1] = 1.0*y - 0.34413*(u-128) - 0.71414*(v-128);   // g
        m_RGB.bits()[i] = 1.0*y + 1.772*(u-128) + 0;                            // b

        y = pData[j+3];
        m_RGB.bits()[i+5] = 1.0*y + 8 + 1.402*(v-128);               // r
        m_RGB.bits()[i+4] = 1.0*y - 0.34413*(u-128) - 0.71414*(v-128);   // g
        m_RGB.bits()[i+3] = 1.0*y + 1.772*(u-128) + 0;
    }


}
```

Comment: where r u allocating memory to m_RGB(QImage)?

Comment: I create an object QImage *m_RGB in the .h file, then m_RGB = new QImage(width, height, QImage::Format_RGB888);

Comment: if its a pointer(m_RGB) how are you calling bits() by `'.'` operator `m_RGB.bits()[i+5]` as well as in the function argument its an not a pointer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create another unsigned char array(say pDataRGB), convert yuv(pData) into rgb(pDataRGB), and then create QImage like-

`QImage *m_RGB = new QImage(pDataRGB, width, height, QImage::Format_RGB888);`

If you want to use only Qimage then setPixel data as following:-

`m_RGB->setPixel(i, j, qRgb(r, g, b));`